# How to center or reposition Mapbox map on annotation after being tapped?

Tags: ios, mapbox

Is there a way to center a Mapbox map onto an annotation after it's been tapped? Or is there a way to reposition the map after an annotation has been opened when the callout view (custom, in this case) is not entirely in view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can center a map view on an annotation by setting the map view's center coordinate to the coordinate of the annotation in [-mapView:didSelectAnnotation:](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.6.3/Protocols/MGLMapViewDelegate.html#/c:objc(pl)MGLMapViewDelegate(im)mapView:didSelectAnnotation:). If you are using annotation views, another option is to set the map view's center coordinate in [-mapView:didSelectAnnotationView:](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.6.3/Protocols/MGLMapViewDelegate.html#/c:objc(pl)MGLMapViewDelegate(im)mapView:didSelectAnnotationView:).

For example:

`- (void)mapView:(MGLMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotation:(id<MGLAnnotation>)annotation {
    mapView.centerCoordinate = annotation.coordinate;
}`